# Upper turn Nocturne

Tags: notation, ornaments

[image]Hi guys,

Anyone know the exact notes to play for this upper turn that is circled in red ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic "shape" of the notes is the same as the symbol: 5 roughly equal length notes C D C B C.

The accidentals above and below the symbol show that the exact notes here are **C D-flat C B-natural C**. Without the natural sign, the "B" would be B-flat, corresponding to the key signature.

Comment: Exquisitely well spelled, alephzero. I'd like to add that some ornaments reflect a composer's/arranger's desire to feel a note without being too specific about just how. Many players haven't the agility to turn all 5 component notes but can trill the same effect one way or another, given how "slowly" our ears react.

Comment: (My favorite performance story is of devising an intricate curl for a jazz solo, after which my hero said something like "you could've gotten that across twice as well without half the trouble.")